# Argument type string is not assignable to parameter type "set-cookie"

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, supertest, supertest-as-promised

I try to do a GET if a error occurs in a previous POST with supertest. The problem is that I am unable to use GET.
This is my code:

```
bookId = await request(app).post("/books/add-one-book").send({
                "name":"bookTest",
                "chapters": 1
        })

if (bookId === undefined) {
   const allBooks = await request(app)
        .get("/books/all-books")
        .set({
               Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
          })
bookId = allBooks;
...
```

The warning says:

> Argument type string is not assignable to parameter type "set-cookie".

The warning for set is:

> Unresolved function or method set()

What did I do wrong? I think supertest don't see the right GET... But I have seen a lot of example on the web and all of them use get like this.
Do you see something?
Thanks.

Comment: No code in images please.  Code should be as text only for a whole bunch of good reasons.

Comment: Ok I have replace the image by text. I hope it is more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you've used ESM import..
There is no default export in 'supertest' module.
Try to import it in this way:

```
import { agent as request } from 'supertest'
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your IDE shows you this warning when importing supertest via `const supertest = require('supertest');` and wrapping your express app with it `const request = supertest(app);`.

I suggest importing supertest's `agent`, instead.

```js
const {agent} = require('supertest');
const {app, start, close} = require('../app'); // import your express app
const request = agent(app); // wrap supertest agent around your express app
```

As [Scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75638012/7018399) said, there is no default export in [supertest module](https://github.com/ladjs/supertest/blob/master/index.js).